# Why UpdateModel() binding of IList does not work, but as a method parameter it does?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple class:

```
[Serializable]
public class RatePerPurpose
{
    public int ValueId { get; set; }

    public double Rate { get; set; }
}
```

, and simple data to POST:

```
<input type="hidden" name="[0].ValueId" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="[0].Rate" value="2.34" />
<input type="hidden" name="[1].ValueId" value="10" />
<input type="hidden" name="[1].Rate" value="20.34" />
```

This works without any problems:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult MyActionPost(List<RatePerPurpose> rates)
{
  // no problem, this works
}
```

My question is, why these does NOT work (I have tested ASP.NET MVC 5)? Or how to change this, to make it work?

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult MyActionPost()
{
  List<RatePerPurpose> rates = new List<RatePerPurpose>();
  this.UpdateModel(rates);
  // This DOES NOT work, 'rates' is empty :-(

  this.UpdateModel(rates, prefix:"");
  // Setting 'none' prefix, also DOES NOT work. 'rates' is still empty
}
```

PS: I have tested `List<>` and `IList<>` also, but same problem occurs.

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean? Are you getting an exception? Is nothing happening? Why are you using `UpdateModel` in the first place?

Comment: `rates` is empty after `UpdateModel()`. (I will edit my question, to be clear)

My actual action method is much bigger, with more parameters and logic. I have just isolated a problem to a simple question. So simple answer is that I need `UpdateModel()`. Period. :-)

Comment: Do you actually have the `List<RatePerPurpose>` as a model? Have you tried wrapping the list in a proper model/view model?

Comment: What is `proper model/view model` ? `List<>` is not a proper model ?

Comment: I just meant wrapping the list in some class that you'll use as model for both the view and the controller. I think one of the points of MVC is that the view and the controller share a single model (that may be a container for a bunch of other classes etc.). `UpdateModel` is designed with this in mind as well - it's not there to pass parameters, it's there to allow you to change the values in an already existing object (e.g. you have a `Person` object in the DB and you want to take it, change the values sent in the request and save it back).

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand. First example works, and second example does not work. Both use same `DefaultModelBinder`, so I don't get it. When I try some different model (let's say some `SimpleClass`, not a collection) then both examples works perfectly. So my question is, why `IList<>` as a model work only as an action parameter and not with `UpdateModel()`.

Comment: Oh wait a second, doesn't `UpdateModel` bind data from current request's form data to an object if member names match? In the last `MyActionPost` there seems to be no form data (i.e. method parameters). So what did you expect to happen there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured it out (after three sleepless days). There were actually two problems.

**Problem 1**

There was buggy `DoubleModelBinder` deeply-fried (registered) in my application's global.asax called on `Application_Start`:

```
...
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(double), new DoubleModelBinder());
...
```

This binder was dependent on `UICulture`, so binding from action method parameter worked. But body of `MyActionPost()` had different culture, so my `DoubleModelBinder` was throwing some internal exception. It is a bit strange, that this exception was not propagated out of `UpdateModel()`.

**Problem 2**

Using `UpdateModel()` (or `TryUpdateModel()`) like in my example is perfectly fine. I have found similar example also in a book [Pro ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.apress.com/9781430265290) from Adam Freeman on page 654, but the "correct" version should use `FormCollection` as a action method parameter. So working example:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult MyActionPost(FormCollection form)
{
  List<RatePerPurpose> rates = new List<RatePerPurpose>();
  this.UpdateModel(rates, "MyList", form);
  // This works, 'rates' is binded properly
}
```

**PS:**

And one last advice. Use `.Index` when binding collections. (It is not required, when indexes are from 0 and there are no gaps between items, but I can sleep better now. :) So data should look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MyList.Index" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="MyList[0].ValueId" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="MyList[0].Rate" value="2.34" />

<input type="hidden" name="MyList.Index" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="MyList[1].ValueId" value="10" />
<input type="hidden" name="MyList[1].Rate" value="20.34" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the second example, you have an empty list. `UpdateModel` will update items *if they exist and it can find a correlation*, but it won't fill an empty list for you. If you instead did something like:

```
var rates = db.RatePerPurposes.ToList();
UpdateModel(rates);
```

*That* would probably work, assuming it could match `RatePerPurpose` instances from the POST body to `RatePerPurpose` instances in what was returned from the database.